# Do final modifiers affect Java serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

Would adding / removing a final modifier on a field affect Java serialization?

I saw in the [java serialization specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678) that changing the access to a field is a compatible change. But there is no mention of the `final` modifier, either in the "Incompatible changes" or the "Compatible changes" section.

Is this a compatible change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you were not changing the value of the field yes, it is compatible.

Comment: I would have loved a link to some specification or documentation that spells this out, but since I didn't specify it in my question, I'll accept your answer :)